# How to enter text in text field using monkeyrunner

Tags: monkeyrunner

i wanted to enter some text to a text field in my android application.I installed the app and in the second page i wanted to search for some places.For that i need to enter some text.

```
I tried `device.press('KEYCODE_BUTTON_SELECT',MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
device.press('KEYCODE_i','DOWN_AND_UP')
device.press('KEYCODE_n','DOWN_AND_UP')
device.press('KEYCODE_d','DOWN_AND_UP')
device.press('KEYCODE_i','DOWN_AND_UP')
device.press('KEYCODE_a','DOWN_AND_UP')
```

or 
    Device.type(India)`

But these commands are not working for my application.,It is not entering string "India" to my application text filed.But this is working with phone native search text filed.

I installed Android View Client and import the following things

```
import from com.dtmilano.android.view client import View Client
from com.android.monkey runner import Monkey Runner, Monkey Device
```

Then i wrote the code like this

```
vc = ViewClient(device)
vc.dump()
address= vc.findViewById('search')
address.type('india')
```

But it is showing error: 'None Type' object has no attribute 'type'.

Can u pls help me in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use:

```
address = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('search')
```

to avoid having to check for a not found `address` field.
Also, I guess the id is `'id/search'`.

And finally a word of warning on:

```
address.type('india')
```

This is `EditText.type()` so you have to be sure that `address` is an  `EditText`

```
print address.getClass()
```

otherwise you can use

```
address.touch() # to focus it
device.type('india')
```

or (because sometimes type() chokes)

```
address.touch() # to focus it
for c in 'india':
    device.type(c)
```

Comment: Hi  I tried the following code..It is not typing the word "india" and showing one user warning "Unsupported Android Version 10"
address = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('id/search')
address.touch()
device.type('india')

Comment: address = vc.findViewByIdOrRaise('search')   address.type('india')..Attribute error is showing.Attribute error-type

Comment: I told you to verify that `address` is actually an EditText or to take device.type() approach

Comment: What's the result of print address.getClass()?

Comment: Actually the text field is "AutoCompleteTextView".There i want to type something.Can u pls help me in doing this.